Expanded synthetic division of polynomials is giving different a remainder than Long division of polynomials
I'm practicing expanded synthetic division of polynomials for an upcoming test, and for some reason I'm getting different remainders than when I check my work via Google. I find it much easier to believe in user error, so where am I going wrong?

The remainder according to Google is
37x^2 - 17x + 23

Shouldn't there also be a blank right triangle in the lower-right, where you have "$37$", "$-111$", and "$384$"?  (You're only subtracting multiples of the quotient, not multiples of the quotient and leading segments of the remainder.  Longer explanation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ib8c96y0_c .)

Oh, that makes sense. If you do the addition (addition of negative numbers, but still addition) without those three it comes out to what Google said. Thank you!

Once you have the quotient $3x-9$ correct you can check by just multiplication.
$$    \left(   x^{3}  + 3 x^{2}  -  x  + 2 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(  3 x  - 9 \right) } = 3x^4 - 30 x^2 + 15 x - 18  $$
Since we want $ \left(  3 x^{4}  + 7 x^{2}  - 2 x  + 5 \right) $
we need to add $37 x^2  - 17x + 23   $
as in
$$  \left(  3x^4 - 30 x^2 + 15 x - 18 \right)  +   \left( 37 x^2  - 17x + 23 \right) = \left( 3 x^{4}  + 7 x^{2}  - 2 x  + 5 \right) $$
$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$
$$  \left(  3 x^{4}  + 7 x^{2}  - 2 x  + 5 \right)  =  \left(   x^{3}  + 3 x^{2}  -  x  + 2 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(  3 x  - 9 \right) } +  \left(  37 x^{2}  - 17 x  + 23 \right)  $$
$$  \left(   x^{3}  + 3 x^{2}  -  x  + 2 \right)  =  \left(  37 x^{2}  - 17 x  + 23 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{ 37 x  + 128 }{ 1369 }  \right) } +  \left(   \frac{  - 44 x  - 206 }{ 1369 }  \right)  $$
$$  \left(  37 x^{2}  - 17 x  + 23 \right)  =  \left(   \frac{  - 44 x  - 206 }{ 1369 }  \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  - 1114366 x  + 5729265 }{ 968 }  \right) } +  \left( \frac{ 442187}{484 } \right)  $$
$$  \left(   \frac{  - 44 x  - 206 }{ 1369 }  \right)  =  \left( \frac{ 442187}{484 } \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  - 21296 x  - 99704 }{ 605354003 }  \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$
$$ \frac{ 0}{1} $$
$$ \frac{ 1}{0} $$
$$ \color{magenta}{  \left(  3 x  - 9 \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(  3 x  - 9 \right) }{ \left( 1  \right) } $$
$$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{ 37 x  + 128 }{ 1369 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{ 111 x^{2}  + 51 x  + 217 }{ 1369 }  \right) }{ \left(   \frac{ 37 x  + 128 }{ 1369 }  \right) } $$
$$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  - 1114366 x  + 5729265 }{ 968 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{  - 90354 x^{3}  + 423021 x^{2}  + 39701 x  + 899433 }{ 968 }  \right) }{ \left(   \frac{  - 30118 x^{2}  + 50653 x  + 536648 }{ 968 }  \right) } $$
$$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  - 21296 x  - 99704 }{ 605354003 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{ 1452 x^{4}  + 3388 x^{2}  - 968 x  + 2420 }{ 442187 }  \right) }{ \left(   \frac{ 484 x^{3}  + 1452 x^{2}  - 484 x  + 968 }{ 442187 }  \right) } $$
$$  \left(  3 x^{4}  + 7 x^{2}  - 2 x  + 5 \right)  \left(   \frac{  - 22 x^{2}  + 37 x  + 392 }{ 646 }  \right)  -  \left(   x^{3}  + 3 x^{2}  -  x  + 2 \right)  \left(   \frac{  - 66 x^{3}  + 309 x^{2}  + 29 x  + 657 }{ 646 }  \right)  =  \left( 1  \right)  $$

Not quite the answer I was looking for (I asked what I was doing wrong with my expanded synthetic division), but this is very helpful regardless. Thank you!
